# Three.js How to point child of Object3d to face camera?

Tags: html, canvas, three.js, 3d

Here is the thing. I have an Object3d that is composed of 6 planes settled to form a cube. Now, after applying quaternion rotation based on mouse input and after the cube has stopped - I need the cube to turn straight to the camera at its closest side (plane child). What I am doing now is I’m getting the current Euler angles of my Object3d matrix, applying rotation to this matrix and setting it back to my object’s quaternion with setFromRotationMatrix() function. Sometimes this method works (usually at low angles) and sometimes the Z axis behaves wrong (or maybe Y, or even all of them, can’t tell).

Now, I certainly could just calculate the closest side and apply direct quaternion of this side to my object, which works, but that gives me no animation.

I’m using this code to get my current angles: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~gewang/projects/darth/stuff/quat_faq.html#Q37. Based on that I calculate the closest 90 degrees rotation for every axis:

```
        function lookAtCamDeg(val){
            var d = 1;
            var s = 1;
            var newAngle;

            if(val < 0)d*=-1;

            val = Math.abs(val);

            if(val <= 45)s*=-1;
            if(val > 45)val=90-val;

            newAngle = val*d*s;

            return newAngle;
        }
```

And applying that to turn my cube:

```
            var angles = getAngles();http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~gewang/projects/darth/stuff/quat_faq.html#Q37
            var newX = lookAtCamDeg(angles.x);
            var newY = lookAtCamDeg(angles.y);
            var newZ = lookAtCamDeg(angles.z);

            var ma = cube.matrix;
            ma = ma.rotateX(-newX*DEGREES)
            ma = ma.rotateY(-newY*DEGREES)
            ma = ma.rotateZ(-newZ*DEGREES)
            cube.quaternion.setFromRotationMatrix(ma);
```

What I am thinking now is to try using separate planes of my cube (children) and based on their normals apply lookAt() method, but don’t know how to do it, since I need to rotate the whole object, not just one child. Could someone please lead me to the right direction to go? What is the best way to achieve my needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The THREE.Quaterion object contains methods for interpolation. So calculate the quaternion value of the original face normal, the quaternion you get here from setFromRotationMatrix(ma), and then apply THREE.Quaterion.slerp() repeatedly to get in-betweens, which can apply to cube.quaternion

Comment: I've never used slerps before, so to say a bit afraid of it:))) The solution I've found is to calculate the difference between 2 quat's with formula TransQ = InitQ^-1 * FinQ, where ^-1 is `conjugate()` function. So then I just create new matrix, apply rotation to it and finally apply this matrix to my object's quat with `setFromRotationMatrix()`. The hard part was to understand how exactly set this whole mess up. Thanks for advise, though!)